# named_scope is creating new objects if I use it with a :join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope

Disclaimer:  My original exposure to Ruby on Rails was literally years ago, and a great many things are new to me now that I'm picking it back up.  One of these things is named scopes.  They seem great, but I'm not getting the result I expect.  Here's a for-instance:

```
class User
  has_many logs
  named_scope :logged_in, :joins => ['logs'], :conditions => ['logs.logout_at IS NULL']
end

Class Log
  belongs_to user
end
```

It is my understanding that doing a

```
User.logged_in
```

should be exactly the same as doing a

```
User.find(:all, :joins => ['logs], :conditions => ['logs.logout_at IS NULL'])
```

But instead, I'm getting back different objects.  To demonstrate:

```
real = User.find_by_name('admin')
  #<User id:12345, name: 'admin' ... >
fake = User.logged_in.find_by_name('admin')
  #<User id: 54321, name: 'admin' ... >
```

So my question is:  Where on earth is this new object coming from, and how do I get named_scope to give me the original one?

Comment: The problem, as it turns out, is with Rails 2.1 and its habit of smashing together the results of joins if you use them in scopes.  Detailed here: http://selfamusementpark.com/blog/2008/07/10/named_scope-joins-includes/

The answer below was an excellent workaround!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
named_scope :logged_in, 
            :conditions => ["logs.logout_at IS NULL"], 
            :include => :logs
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple users named 'admin'

Try this:

```
User.find_all_by_name('admin')
```

Comment: Sadly, it's not the easy answer; that query returns exactly one result, the one I've labeled 'real' up there.